# Making a DLL to access to an external class object

Tags: c#

I am aware that the title is not self-explanatory but this is the simplest one that I came up with.

Basically, I am have a .NET DLL and a .NET forms application. In this form, I load this DLL and create a class let's say:

```
MyClass a = new MyClass();
```

I have:

```
public string DataBridge
{
 get { return String.Empty; }
 set { txtHistory.Text += value + "\r\n"; }
}
```

in my form and I want to access this `DateBridge` string within MyClass which is located inside my .NET DLL.

I am not sure if it's clear, let me know if there is a point that you didn't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .NET Forms application must have a reference to the .NET dll. If you're programming with Visual Studio, you can simply right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer, then choose "Add Reference", and find the DLL that contains MyClass.

Since you can have multiple projects open in one Solution, you can choose to add a reference to your MyClass project rather than the DLL file, this will make sure that changes in your MyClass automatically will be visible in your .NET Forms project.

If you don't use Visual Studio, but some other tool (eg. SharpDevelop), please see that tool's documentation to find out how to add a reference tho another project or dll.

If you don't use a tool at all, but use the CSC.exe compiler to compile you code, see the compiler's documentation to find out how to include a reference to an external dll at compile time.

Comment: While this is correct, it does not address the inherent flaw in the design which causes a circular dependency between the two projects.

Answer (score 1):

`MyClass` will need to have a reference of your form.

Answer (score 0):

`MyClass` can not know about your Form (or your Form does not know about `MyClass`) as this would create a circular dependency. You need to pass something that both parties knows about. An interface or a delegate could be suitable in this case. Unfortunately c# does can not create delegates to properties.

First I want to note some things about you `DataBridge`.

1. `get { return String.Empty; }` if you don't need to use the result you can skip the getter and only use the setter.
2. `set { txtHistory.Text += value + "\r\n"; }`, this as a quite bad design, setters should not have this kind of side effects. If you assign a setter the same value multiple times you expect it to produce the same result as if you just assigned it once.
   Your `DataBridge` should rather be a method (like `DataBridgeAppend(string s)`).

If you instead create a method

```
public string DataBridgeAppend(string s)
{
    txtHistory.Text += s + Environment.Newline;
    // or even better  txtHistory.AppendText(s + Environment.Newline);
}
```

You can change your class to this

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Action<string> _dataBridgeAppend;
    public MyClass(Action<string> dataBridgeAppend)
    {
        _dataBridgeAppend = dataBridgeAppend;
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        // stuff
        _dataBridgeAppend("result"); // using the callback delegate to return stuff to the Form
    }
}
```

from Form1 you instantiate `MyClass` like this

```
MyClass a = new MyClass(this.DataBridgeAppend);
```